# Retrieve data in Android using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a newbie to Firebase and I'm trying to get data from cloud to my project

```
DatabaseReference userRef = ref.child(user.getUid());

    userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserDoctor userDoctor = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDoctor.class);
            tempName = userDoctor.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But the problem is I couldn't assign the string to the tempName, it returned "null"

[This is my debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29yLC.png)

And the UserDoctor class is here

```
public class UserDoctor {
public String address;
public String major;
public String mobile;
public String name;
public String workplace;

public UserDoctor(){}

public UserDoctor(String _address, String _major, String _mobile, String _name, String _workplace){
    name = _name;
    address = _address;
    major = _major;
    mobile = _mobile;
    workplace = _workplace;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

Thank you very much!

Comment: As your debug window shows, the name of the doctor is being property read and set. The problem is not reading the data from Firebase. The problem is more likely *when* you are trying to use `tempName`. Data is read from Firebase asynchronously and most likely simply hasn't been read yet when you are using `tempName`. See my answer here for a long explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen First of all, thanks for your answer, I've read the link you gave but I'm so confused and don't know what to do with this. So I can't use the semaphore, right?. Can you suggest me a way to get the doctor's name?

Comment: Your code already *gets* the doctor's name. But you show nowhere how your using it. Typically you'll need to move all the code that *uses* `tempName` *into* `onDataChange()`.

Comment: intent.putExtra("userName", tempName);
I already did it, but it seemed not worked well

Comment: That depends on where you use that code. If the link I provided (which is the most likely cause, I'm quite certain of that) doesn't help you solve the problem, please edit your question to include a [single, minimal snippet of code that completely reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful).